# Core data delete objects

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4, ios5

I use core data in my application. When I delete object with `[context deleteObject:obj]`, object is not deleted only with empty fields. How can I delete object permanently? Thanks in advanced. I use table view and when this view is filled with data from core data, there are empty rows where were deleted objects. This is the code:

```
LNAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
self.accounts = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Accounts" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;

self.accounts = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: What do you mean, only with empty fields? What sort of UI are you using to show these objects? A lot more information is needed here.

Comment: Are you using a fetched results controller to handle filling/updating the table view?

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin You can see the code in my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you making sure to save the context after you make the change?

```
NSError *error = nil;
if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
  /*
   //Handle error
  */
  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Also make sure that you are referencing the correct context, as you can have more than one.

Comment: when you are deleting are you also using self.context or just context?